# Как сделать плавное появление блоков при загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать плавное появление блоков при загрузке страницы?
Я попробовал через fadeIn (подключил файл jq в шапку, создал файл common.js , закинул туда код)

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $("#bf_container").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Но безрезультатно

Comment: а что значит `$(window).ready` ? ........может все же `$(document).ready` или `$(window).load` ?

Comment: Это значит,  что окна закрыты и не дует ветер 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть дело в том, что блок `#bf_container` уже отображен?
Попробуйте скрыть его и запустить по `$(document).ready`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. #bf_container был изначально отоброжен.